# Issue while converting string data to decimal in proper format in sparksql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am facing issue in `spark sql` while converting `string` to `decimal(15,7)`.

Input data is:

```
'0.00'
'28.12'
'-39.02'
'28.00'
```

I have tried converting it into `float` and then converting into `decimal` but got unexpected results.

```
sqlContext.sql("select cast(cast('0.00' as float) as decimal(15,7)) from table").show()
```

The result I received is as follows

```
0
```

But I need to have data in the below format:

```
0.0000000
28.1200000
-39.0200000
28.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the format_number method. Something like this.

```py
df.withColumn("num", format_number(col("value").cast("decimal(15,7)"), 7)).show()
```

The results should be like this.

```py
+------+-----------+
| value|        num|
+------+-----------+
|  0.00|  0.0000000|
| 28.12| 28.1200000|
|-39.02|-39.0200000|
| 28.00| 28.0000000|
+------+-----------+
```